# How to Pass The Context From The Middleware Down The Chain In .NET Minimal APIs

Tags: c#, .net

Given the below code in `Program.cs`, how can I pass the context (or any other data for that matter) in the `app.Use` method to the following post method? I would like to use the context to get the remote IP address that sent the request.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    using (LogContext.PushProperty("FILE", "Program.cs"))
    using (LogContext.PushProperty("METHOD", "app.Use()"))
    {
        IPAddress remoteIp;

        if (context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress == null)
            remoteIp = IPAddress.Parse("::1").MapToIPv6();
        else
            remoteIp = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv6();

        logger.Information("Request from Remote IP address: {RemoteIP}", remoteIp);

        if (IpWhitelist.ipWhitelist == null)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            return;
        }

        if (!IpWhitelist.ipWhitelist.ContainsKey(remoteIp.ToString()) && !IpWhitelist.ipWhitelist.ContainsKey(remoteIp.MapToIPv6().ToString()))
        {
            logger.Information("Forbidden Request from Remote IP address: {IP}", remoteIp);
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
            return;
        }

    }
    await next.Invoke(context);
});

app.MapPost("/test", async (Request request)=>
{

});
```

Comment: You already have all these things. Check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/use-http-context?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0). Any extra services you want can be added as parameters and will be filled through dependency injection. The [IP Safelist page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/ip-safelist?view=aspnetcore-7.0) in the docs shows 3 different ways to create safe lists: as middleware, action filters or page filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just as @Panagiotis commented on my question, I already have all the required information. I need only to access it like below:

```
                    
app.MapPost("/Test", async (TestRequest testRequest, HttpContext context) =>
                    
{
                            
 string? ip = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();                       
                    
});
```